# Configuring AEM 6.0 with SOLR

Tags: solr, aem

I am trying to configure AEM 6.0 with remote SOLR (4.10.2). I followed the steps and recommended config files mentioned in https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/upgrade/queries-and-indexing.html#Configuring AEM with a single remote SOLR server

On the SOLR server I am getting

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field path_exact
```

at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1269)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1221)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.getPrefixQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:757)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.handleBareTokenQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:299)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:185)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:107)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:96)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.parse(SolrQueryParserBase.java:151)
    at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParser.java:50)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:141)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.getQuery(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:354)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.deleteByQuery(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:384)

**AND**

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id
at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getIndexedId(AddUpdateCommand.java:93)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:939)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:692)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:247)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:174)
at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:99)
at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1967)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
```

And in my AEM logs I am getting

```
equest: http://localhost:8983/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=2
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer$Runner.run(ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer.java:240)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

08.05.2016 12:54:59.849 *ERROR* [concurrentUpdateScheduler-1-thread-1] org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer error
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad Request

Not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

although this is an old question, probably still relevant. 
Most likely your schema does not match the data to index. You can either import the Configuration provided by [Jackrabbit](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit-oak/tree/trunk/oak-solr-core/src/main/resources/solr/oak/conf), write your own schema or use the [ManagedIndexSchemaFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schemaless+Mode) (available since Solr 5 afaik).

You don't necessarily need to use Solr 4, you can also go for a newer version.

Please also have a look at this [Blog-Post](https://www.dev-eth0.de/blog/2017/02/27/solr-aem.html) about the setup of AEM with Solr (including a sample application)